# Показ своего макета под элементом RecyclerView после свайпа

Tags: android, recyclerview, swipe

Хочу чтобы **после свайпа** элемента в `RecyclerView`, отображался **кастомный макет** с тремя кнопками. В ходе поисков, решение вроде как нашлось. Но у меня оно почему то не до конца работает.

Вот ссылка на пост с кодом решения - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35667044/8013212

Если делать один в один как в примере, то после свайпа виден `clipBackground`, с левой стороны. Но любые попытки изменить выравнивание, делают его невидимым. Помогите разобраться почему так происходит и как вообще изменить выравнивание, например сделать по центру?

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под свайпом элемента в RecyclerView?

Comment: @IvanVovk, сдвигание элемента вправо/влево, от слова "swipe".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все дело в **способе отрисовки** макета. Там используются не координаты, а границы отрисовки, где 0/0 - верхний левый угол экрана.

В указанном решении `clipBackground` размещается справа и рисуется оттуда же. Изменение выравнивания и стороны отрисовки, при использовании `backgroundView.setRight(0)`, приводит к тому что фоновый макет размещается за пределами экрана, либо при его ширина остается равной `0`.

Например, для отрисовки `clipBackground` при свайпе влево, я сначала перемещал его вправо.

```
backgroundView.setRight(itemView.getWidth());
backgroundView.setLeft(itemView.getWidth());
```

А потом отрисовывал из этого положения. Путем изменения ширины, сдвигая левую границу макета.

```
backgroundView.setLeft(itemView.getWidth() + (int) dX);
```